# Get Modern theme

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme, modern

Is there any way to get the custom modern theme being used by a site collection? I'm trying to reproduce a bunch of site collections and I'd rather not have to do this by hand.

There is an ApplyTheme method but no get theme? 
ThemeInfo only seems to be classic themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to check out the property

[Web.ThemedCssFolderUrl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt807040(v=office.15))

When a site's theme has been customized, a new folder will be generated and stored under _catalogs/theme/Themed/XXX and this property contains the reference to to it.

If I'm not mistaken this stands true for both classic and modern themes.

You should be able to get and set this properly rather than ApplyTheme() which could potentially generate unwanted instances of the same theme.

More on this here,

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12298962-make-the-themedcssfolderurl-property-of-the-web-ob

Comment: Thanks, I did see that but it never clicked what it was for.